# Create a function to calculate median cost across different years

Tags: python, pandas, function, median

I have a sample dataset which contains id and costs in diff years as the one below:

| Id | 2015-04 | 2015-05 | 2015-06 | 2015-07 | 2016-04 | 2016-05 | 2016-06 | 2016-07 | 2017-04 | 2017-05 | 2017-06 | 2017-07 | 2018-04 | 2018-05 | 2018-06 | 2018-07 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 58500 | 58500 | 58300 | 57800 | 57500 | 57700 | 57800 | 57800 | 57800 | 57900 | 58400 | 59000 | 59500 | 59500 | 59000 | 58500 |
| 11 | 104600 | 104600 | 105700 | 106100 | 106300 | 107300 | 108000 | 107600 | 107800 | 108300 | 109200 | 109600 | 109300 | 108700 | 109000 | 110700 |
| 12 | 104900 | 106700 | 107900 | 107500 | 106100 | 105200 | 105700 | 106400 | 106700 | 107100 | 107200 | 107100 | 107500 | 108300 | 109200 | 110500 |
| 13 | 50500 | 49600 | 48900 | 48400 | 48100 | 48000 | 47700 | 47500 | 47400 | 47600 | 47800 | 47800 | 47600 | 47600 | 48100 | 48400 |
| 14 | 49800 | 49900 | 50300 | 50800 | 51100 | 51200 | 51200 | 51400 | 51600 | 51900 | 52400 | 52600 | 52300 | 51800 | 51100 | 50900 |

How can I create a function in Python to find the median cost of each year belonging to their respective id? I want the function to be dynamic in terms of the start and end year so that if new data comes for different years, the code will calculate the changes accordingly. For example, if new data comes for 2019, the end date would automatically be considered as 2019 instead of 2018 and calculate its median respectively.

With the current data sample given above, the result should look something like one below:

| Id | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 58400 | 57750 | 58150 | 59250 |
| 11 | 105150 | 107450 | 108750 | 109150 |
| 12 | 107100 | 105900 | 107100 | 108750 |
| 13 | 49250 | 47850 | 47700 | 47850 |
| 14 | 50100 | 51200 | 52150 | 51450 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we split the column names on `-` and get only the year. Then we groupby over `axis=1` based on these years and take the median:

```
df = df.set_index("Id")
df = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split("-").str[0], axis=1).median().reset_index()
# or get first 4 characters
# df = df.groupby(df.columns.str[:4], axis=1).median().reset_index()
```

```
   Id    2015    2016    2017    2018
0  10   58400   57750   58150   59250
1  11  105150  107450  108750  109150
2  12  107100  105900  107100  108750
3  13   49250   47850   47700   47850
4  14   50100   51200   52150   51450
```

Comment: Yes, bit less general, but suffices in this case. Added to the answer @Ch3steR

Comment: Yes agreed. Upvoted already. It's best to cover all the cases.